# How to filter dataframe and make a subset at once pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to make a subselection of a dataframe based on some columns, while at the same time filtering the dataframe based on a different column. In SQL it looks like this:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3,
FROM table
WHERE colume_4 = some_value
```

I know how to do it in two steps, but I prefer doing it in one operation. Does anyone know how to do this in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with combination with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df.loc[df.colume_4 == some_value, ['col1','col2','col3']]
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way:

```
df[df['col4']==3].filter(['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])
```